# Unable to connect other drivers,that installed in windows operating system

Tags: hard-drive

I had installed Windows7 and I want to try the Ubuntu. I had choose the dual booting system. After that I choose to Ubuntu to work with, but there is no option to select my drivers and access those files that I can saved through my windows7 operating system.

In Windows there is one icon My computer that shows all the drivers in that systems, unfortunately there is no option in Ubuntu to select that files. In Ubuntu there is only access to Home folders, no others folders. Eg I had C,E and F drive in my system using Windows Fat partition system I have easy access with My computer option in Window, but in Ubuntu there is no option to access those files.

If there is any icon like My computer instead of Home folder icon it is very easy to access all the files.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well, you want the My Computer menu on your desktop. It's simple:

1. Download the following link: https://copy.com/pUp0PtnwH69v.
2. Drag the downloaded file to the desktop (or where you want).
3. Right-click the file, go to Properties > Permissions. Check the box titled *Allow executing file as program*.

That simple. Here's a simple screenshot as an example:

[image]